# How do we make a gadget's height 100%?

Tags: javascript, google-sites

Good afternoon all,

I'm using Google Sites and I'm trying to embed a gadget (iFrame) into the site. It is working fine, however Google Sites does not allow us to make the gadget expand to fill its content's height. It only allows 100% width and a fixed height:

[image]

since we are allowed to have our own javascript running in the embedded gadget (iFrame), I'm trying to fix the issue by dynamically calculating the height in pixels, getting a reference to the parent page's Dom's [HTMLIFrameElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/HTMLIFrameElement), and modifying the height from there.

From my custom gadget file (iFrame), I can get a reference to the parent [Window](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window) object, however **parent.document** returns `undefined`.

This is my custom gadget file [g5.xml](https://sites.google.com/site/pacerierfiles/g5.xml):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<Module>
    <ModulePrefs title="My Gadget" /> 
    <Content type="html">
<![CDATA[
<script>
document.body.onload = function(){
    var content_height = document.getElementById('content').clientHeight;
    alert(parent); // [object DOMWindow]
    alert(parent.document); // undefined
};
</script>
<div id="content">
    some<br>content<br>here
</div>
]]>
    </Content> 
</Module>
```

Is there any way to access an iFrame's parent's DOM elements if **parent.document** returns `undefined`?

Are there any other solutions to make a gadget 100% height in Google Sites?